# Can I used a Toshiba H200 easily in a Desktop?

Tags: ssd, desktop-computer

I have bought a Toshiba H200 by accident and was wondering if I could use it in my Desktop as it is a laptop/gaming console SSHD?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to use the drive. It just combines the benefits of an SSD and a normal hard drive but doesn't change the drive physically. Just make sure you check the connections and make sure you have SATA cable already in your computer or to go get one.

Comment: Instead of commenting "thank you" consider marking it as an answer and reading up on [what you should be doing](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) after you get an answer.